# itext7 pdf merge with bookmarks

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation, bookmarks, itext7

I am trying to merge two pdfs src1 ad src2 with bookmarks, I have used itext7 to merge the pdfs. pdfs getting merged properly but bookmarks not working properly, bookmarks from scr1 pdf always points to scr2 pdf respectively in the merged document.

scr1 bookmark1 ==> points to src2 bookmark1

```
dfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(DEST));
PdfMerger merger = new PdfMerger(pdfDoc);
PdfDocument srcDoc1 = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC1));
PdfOutline rootOutline = pdfDoc.getOutlines(false);
PdfOutline srcOutline = srcDoc1.getOutlines(false);

PdfDocument srcDoc2 = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC2));
merger.merge(srcDoc1, 1, srcDoc1.getNumberOfPages());
merger.merge(srcDoc2, 1, srcDoc2.getNumberOfPages());

merger.close();
srcDoc1.close();
srcDoc2.close();
pdfDoc.close();
```

bookmarks for source one pdf is always pointing the source 2 pdf and source 2 pdf bookmarks are working properly in merged pdf document.

Any one please help me to fix this issue, I have tried several ways to repointing the destination and override the destination point in the merge document noting not worked out properly.

```
dfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(DEST));
PdfMerger merger = new PdfMerger(pdfDoc);
PdfDocument srcDoc1 = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC1));
PdfOutline rootOutline = pdfDoc.getOutlines(false);

PdfOutline srcOutline = srcDoc1.getOutlines(false);
PdfDocument srcDoc2 = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC2));

merger.merge(srcDoc1, 1, srcDoc1.getNumberOfPages());
merger.merge(srcDoc2, 1, srcDoc2.getNumberOfPages());

for(PdfOutline o : rootOutline.getAllChildren()) {      
    o.addDestination(PdfDestination.makeDestination(new PdfString(o.getTitle().toString())));
}

merger.close();
srcDoc1.close();
srcDoc2.close();
pdfDoc.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution It is working properly after renaming the destination to unique one before merge

```
PdfDocument srcDoc1 = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC1));
PdfDocument srcDoc2 = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC2));
PdfDocument srcDoc3 = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC3));

renameDest(srcDoc1);
renameDest(srcDoc2);
renameDest(srcDoc3);

merger.merge(srcDoc1, 1, srcDoc1.getNumberOfPages());
merger.merge(srcDoc2, 1, srcDoc2.getNumberOfPages());
merger.merge(srcDoc3, 1, srcDoc3.getNumberOfPages());

merger.close();
srcDoc1.close();
srcDoc2.close();
srcDoc3.close();
pdfDoc.close();
```

// Method: renameDest

```
public static void renameDest(PdfDocument pdf) {

    try {
        String prefix = "cus-" + (index++) + "-";
        PdfNameTree destsTree = pdf.getCatalog().getNameTree(PdfName.Dests);
        PdfNameTree newNameTree = new PdfNameTree(pdf.getCatalog(), PdfName.Dests);
        for (Map.Entry<String, PdfObject> entry : destsTree.getNames().entrySet()) {
            newNameTree.addEntry(prefix + entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, PdfObject> entry : newNameTree.getNames().entrySet()) {
            destsTree.addEntry(prefix + entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() +"==>>"+ entry.getValue());
        }

        PdfOutline rootOutline = pdf.getOutlines(false);
        updateOutlines(rootOutline, prefix);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

//Method: updateOutlines

```
public static void updateOutlines(PdfOutline parentOutline, String prefix) {
    for (PdfOutline outline : parentOutline.getAllChildren()) {
        updateOutlines(outline, prefix);
    }
    if (parentOutline.getDestination() instanceof PdfStringDestination) {
        parentOutline.addDestination(new PdfStringDestination(prefix + ((PdfString) parentOutline.getDestination().getPdfObject()).getValue()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That sounds remarkably like a bug.

IIRC, there are several different formats bookmarks can use... they could just be "page 7", or "this viewing area on this page object regardless of which page number it happens to be", and several things in between.

Your solution:

1) Get yourself a copy of the PDF Spec (presumably Adobe still hosts it, though I haven't had the need to look at it in close to 10 years.

2) Look at the sections on "bookmarks" and "destinations".

3) When you import any PDF, go through its bookmarks, and make sure all the destinations are of the "page object" variety.  You may have to convert them "manually", or iText may provide this as a feature.  It's been a LONG TIME since I worked on iText, no idea what they've bolted on since then.

Incidentally, page links can be destinations too... so those handy TOC and glossary links could all be just as broken.

You'll need to use the basic object-level PDF manipulators... PdfString, PdfDictionary, PdfArray, etc... I suggest iText-RUPS.  It lets you view a PDF at that basic object level, so you can see what's there and code to match.  There are a number of such programs floating around, but that's the only one whose name I remember off the top of my head.